# Show/Hide div onClick

Tags: reactjs

I currently have my toggle action in place but the only help I need is that, I would like to close the div as well, like an toggle action. The one that I've currently done is that once I click on another div element the previous one that has been clicked closes, but I'd rather prefer that I have an toggle action on closing and opening on the div element being clicked, without needing to click on another just to close the previous div, I've only grabbed the parts that are needed in the code, just to prevent on copying and pasting the whole file, just to save time on reading.

## Code Snippet

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [commentState, commentChange] = useState({
    activeObject: null
  });

  const toggleComment = (index) => {
    commentChange({...commentState, activeObject: posts[index]})
  }

  const toggleActiveStyles = (index) => {
    if(posts[index] === commentState.activeObject) {
      return "dashboard__commentContent toggle";
    } else {
      return "dashboard__commentContent";
    }
  }


 return error ? (
    <span>{error}</span>
  ) : (
  
  {posts.map((post, i) => (
       <button onClick={() => toggleComment(i)} >toggle</button>


       <div className={toggleActiveStyles(i)}>
           <h1>{post.title}</h1>
       </div>
  )}
```

Comment: what does `toggleComment` do?

Comment: @SinanYaman apologies, I've must have left it out, but I've updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-wescoff-fl0v9?file=/src/App.js) that you can manipulate to fit to your needs.

#### Explanation

You would want to keep track of *toggled* divs and make sure to adjust your class based on that. You can filter out or add to the toggled divs state variable, and do whatever you want while rendering.

#### Code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const DATA = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

export default function App() {
  const [closedDivs, setClosedDivs] = useState([]);

  const toggleDiv = (i) => {
    setClosedDivs((divs) =>
      divs.includes(i) ? divs.filter((d) => d !== i) : [...divs, i]
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {DATA.map((d, i) => (
        <div
          className={`${closedDivs.includes(i) ? "close" : ""} box`}
          onClick={() => toggleDiv(i)}
        >
          <p> {d} </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking where does the divs.includes() fall in place? or the divs over all, what data is being received. I've tried implementing it, so I'm just trying to see where my mistake is.

Comment: Since we toggle the divs to open/close, what I do in `toggleDivs` function is that I remove the index of the div from the array if it is present, or add to the array if it is not present. `.includes()` is checking if the index is in the array or not. If you have an object as array elements, you can use something like `.find()` or `.some()` or `.filter(...).length > 0`

Comment: I see the issue was due to the wrong css class called, therefor it's working now, thank you so much!